# Custom App Bar | Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, menuitem, appbar

I'm trying to customize the Menu Items in my Windows Phone Application. Normally it looks like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button3.png" Text="Button 3"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button4.png" Text="Button 4"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Instead of *MenuItem 1* I'd like to implement the ColorSlider from Coding4Fun:

```
xmlns:fun="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls"

<fun:ColorSlider x:Name="colorSlider" Color="{Binding BGColor, Mode=TwoWay}" Orientation="Horizontal"  Height="50" />
```

I'd like to achieve this: [image]

Unfortunately, I can't do anything within the *shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem*. Any possibility on how to achieve this?

Comment: The built-in application bar doesn't allow for this level of customization. If you want to achieve this result, you have no choice but building your own application bar

Comment: Any code samples or tutorials on how to start building own application bars (or other objects, just so I know how I have to start)? I've never done something like this before.